# how can create a directory, in add site command using appcmd.exe?

Tags: iis, windows-command-prompt, appcmd

When I am using the appcmd.exe for creating a website, I need a physical Path address in the command. How can I create directory when I am running this address:

```
%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd.exe add site /name:websitename /id:4 /physicalPath:C:\inetpub\wwwroot\example12 /bindings:http/*:80:example.com
```

On above command, "example12" directory doesn`t exist. And I want when running a command, that directory creating that address Automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never really used `Appcmd.exe` but it is for manipulating IIS objects not file system objects. So I don't think there is a way to automatically create a directory when using AppCmd.exe

In your batch file just use:

```
md C:\inetpub\wwwroot\example12
%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd.exe add site /name:websitename /id:4 /physicalPath:C:\inetpub\wwwroot\example12 /bindings:http/*:80:example.com
```

or better use PowerShell cmdlets rather than `AppCmd.exe`